# Going to next activity once the list is complete

Tags: java, android

So I am working on a project and I don't know much about the android studio. So what I am doing is, I am using jsoup as my web parser and I am creating a list of products from e-commerce websites. So I want that once I get all the details from the parser, then my next activity starts. Till now I am using handler and setting some delay time in it. But that is not helping because sometimes it takes more than 3-4 seconds. 
Below is the code by which I am sending the **allproduct ArrayList** and **producturl ArrayList**

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                                args.putSerializable("ARRAYLIST", (Serializable) allproducts);
                                args.putSerializable("URLLINKS", (Serializable) producturl);
                                intent.putExtra("BUNDLE", args);
                                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TEXT, searchtext);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        }, 6500);
```

Sometimes the listview shows only 2 websites result and sometimes it shows every website.

```
private class Snapdeal extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {
        ArrayList<String> tempurlstore = new ArrayList<>();
        String link;
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> s) {
            String product;
            String urlstore;
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                product = s.get(j);
                urlstore = tempurlstore.get(j);
                allproducts.add(product);
                producturl.add(urlstore);
            }
            String seemore = "See more products on website....";
            allproducts.add(seemore);
            producturl.add(link);

        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(strings[0]).get();
                Elements links = doc.getElementsByClass("col-xs-6  favDp product-tuple-listing js-tuple ");
                ArrayList<String> mainlist = new ArrayList<String>();
                mainlist.add("SNAPDEAL");
                link = strings[0];
                tempurlstore.add("https://www.snapdeal.com");


                for (Element link : links) {
                    String temp1 = null, temp2 = null, temp3 = null, temp4 = null, temp5 = null;
                    String permanent1 = null;

                    Elements elLink = link.getElementsByTag("a");

                    Elements eltitle = link.getElementsByClass("product-title"); //for product title

                    Elements elpricebefore = link.getElementsByClass("lfloat product-desc-price strike ");

                    Elements elpriceafter = link.getElementsByClass("lfloat product-price");

                    Elements discount = link.getElementsByClass("product-discount");


                    //product title loop
                    for (Element titleOfProduct : eltitle) {
                        temp1 = "Title: " + titleOfProduct.text();
                    }

                    //product original price loop
                    for (Element priceOfProductBefore : elpricebefore) {
                        temp2 = "Price before: " + priceOfProductBefore.text();
                    }

                    //product discounted price loop
                    for (Element priceOfProductAfter : elpriceafter) {
                        temp3 = "Discounted price: " + priceOfProductAfter.text();
                    }

                    //discount in number loop
                    for (Element productdiscount : discount) {
                        temp4 = "Discount: " + productdiscount.text();
                    }

                    ArrayList<String> linkArray = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (Element elementLink : elLink) {
                        String MainLink = elementLink.attr("href");
                        linkArray.add(MainLink);
                    }

                    for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
                        temp5 = linkArray.get(0);
                    }

                    if (elpricebefore.text()==null)
                    {
                        permanent1 = "\n" + temp1 + "\n" + "Price :" + elpriceafter.text() + "\n" + temp4 + "\n";
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        permanent1 ="\n" +  temp1 + "\n" + temp2 + "\n" + temp3 + "\n" + temp4 + "\n";

                    }
                    mainlist.add(permanent1);
                    tempurlstore.add(temp5);

                }
                return mainlist;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                ArrayList<String> exception = new ArrayList<String>();
                String ex = e.toString();
                exception.add(ex);
                return exception;
            }
        }
    }
```

Above is some part of my project. So this is how I am taking all the products and all from the parser.
So how can I do this that once all the products are ready in the Arraylist then only intent gets started?
Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Please add your sourcecode and what you have tried so far.

Comment: I added a few lines. The whole code is of more than 1000 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a timer instead of a callback from your parser? This is creating a race condition which is at the heart of your issue. The only way around it is to fire your intent only after your parser is complete.

Without seeing the parser code it is tough to know the exact place to add your hook.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a handler for that. What you could do is use an Observer or use Android's Live Data so the one you choose can let you know when the list is ready so you can start the activity.